# gcc - how to auto instrument every basic block

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation

GCC has an [auto-instrument options for function entry/exit.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html)

> **-finstrument-functions** Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. Just after function entry and just before function
>   exit, the following profiling functions will be called with the
>   address of the current function and its call site. (On some platforms,
>   __builtin_return_address does not work beyond the current function, so the call site information may not be available to the profiling
>   functions otherwise.)
>             void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
>                                            void *call_site);
>             void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
>                                            void *call_site);

I would like to have something like this for every ["basic block"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) so that I can log, dynamically, execution of every branch.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can't. Not with GCC alone at least.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what would be the rough outline of how to do it? I'm thinking: code -> pre-processor output -> use Python to add your own functions at every `{}` -> continue compilation . . . 
Is there another way?

Comment: Some people will object, but you could use some macros to enclose the blocks of interest. Then yeah, you will get away with GCC only.

Comment: If you're going to manually insert your own instrumentation then I don't see why you would do it to preprocessed code instead of letting the preprocessor assist you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what do you mean? Wouldn't it be easier to insert your own code after it's been pre-processed? Cause then your Python script wouldn't have to deal with macros and stuff.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is for code that already exists. Lots and LOTS of code.

Comment: The main problem I see is that  the presence of `{}` is neither necessary nor a sufficient property of "basic block" .

Comment: @EugeneSh. Let's say I'd be happy with auto-instrumenting `{}` :)

Comment: Then just Search/Replace `{` to `BLOCK_START` and `}` to `BLOCK_END`. Well, it might have some false positives in case of array initializes for instance...

Comment: @Adrian, I mean exactly what EugeneSh. said immediately prior to me.

Comment: Hmm, @EugeneSh., I don't think a non-contextual search and replace works.  It will catch too much -- initializers, and structure and union declarations, at least.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, I noted in in the edit. Well, for full automation I guess a parser would be needed.

Comment: Indeed so.  And that applies no matter how or when you instrument C source code.  In particular, preprocessing first does not help with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fuzzer called [American Fuzzy Lop](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/), it solves very similar problem of instrumenting jumps between basic blocks to gather *edge coverage*: if basic blocks are vertices what jumps (edges) were encountered during execution. It may be worth to see its sources. It has three approaches:

- `afl-gcc` is a wrapper for gcc that substitutes `as` by a wrapper rewriting assembly code according to basic block labels and jump instructions
- plugin for Clang compiler
- patch for QEMU for instrumenting already compiled code

Another and probably the simplest option may be to use [DynamoRIO](https://github.com/DynamoRIO/dynamorio) dynamic instrumentation system. Unlike QEMU, it is specially designed to implement custom instrumentation (either as rewriting machine code by hand or simply inserting calls that even may be automatically inlined in some cases, if I get documentation right). If you think dynamic instrumentation is something very hard, look at their examples -- they are only about 100-200 lines (but you still need to read their documentation at least [here](http://dynamorio.org/docs/using.html) and for used functions since it may contain important points: for example [DR constructs dynamic basic blocks, which are distinct from a compiler's classic basic blocks](http://dynamorio.org/docs/dr__events_8h.html#a13e10779d8f91465a0b7aefdf4d87d16)). With dynamic instrumentation you can even instrument used system libraries. In case it is not what you want, you may use something like

```c
static module_data_t *traced_module;

// in dr_client_main
traced_module = dr_get_main_module();

// in basic block event handler
void *app_pc = dr_fragment_app_pc(tag);
if (!dr_module_contains_addr(traced_module, app_pc)) {
    return DR_EMIT_DEFAULT;
}
```